# Forcing sudo to prompt for a password

Tags: sudo, password

If I do the following:

```
sudo su -
//enter password
exit
exit
//login again straight away
sudo su -
```

The second invocation of sudo does not request a password because even though I have logged out again, I am still within some time limit meaning that I do not need to be prompted for my password again.

Because I am trying out some new privs to make sure they work, this is really slowing me down while I wait for the timeout to happen.

Is there a command I can run to reset the timeout?

I don't want to change the timeout or affect other users, by the way!

Comment: If you still cannot force sudo to prompt for password, you may also need to comment user rules mentioning "NOPASSWD" if they are present in `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. I have the line `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` in `/etc/sudoers` and though that the line is disabled by a comment but it looks like the `#` before `includedir` is not read as a comment!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`sudo -k` Will kill the timeout timestamp. You can even put the command afterwards, like `sudo -k test_my_privileges.sh`

From `man sudo`:

> **-K** The -K (sure kill) option is like -k except that it removes the
> user's time stamp entirely and may not
> be used in conjunction with a command
> or other option.  This option does not
> require a password.
>
> **-k** When used by itself, the -k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the
> user's time stamp by setting the time
> on it to the Epoch.  The next time
> sudo is run a password will be
> required.  This option does not
> require a password and was added to
> allow a user to revoke sudo
> permissions from a .logout file.
> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may
> require a password, this option  will cause sudo
> to ignore the user's
> cached credentials.   As a result, sudo will prompt for a password
> (if one is required by the security policy) and will not update the
> user's cached credentials.

You can also change it permanently.
From `man sudoers`:

> **timestamp_timeout**
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo
> will ask for a passwd again.  The
> timeout may include a fractional
> component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.  The
> default is 5.  Set this to 0 to always
> prompt for a password.  If set to a
> value less than 0 the user's timestamp will never expire.
> This can be used to allow users to
> create or delete their own timestamps
> via sudo -v and sudo -k respectively.

Comment: Take care `sudo -k command` will **not** remove the credentials. It just ignores the current credentials and does not store them.

Comment: Just to add to this. If you want to change the timestamp timeout, you need to edit the `sudoers` file with `sudo visudo`. Then you add the line `Defaults timestamp_timeout = 0` at the end of the list of other `Defaults` in the file. Take the line out again to revert back to "normal" timeout.

Comment: My followup-question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416039/26152

Comment: @user1346466 pls can you expand the explanation about your comment?

Comment: @ManuelJordan just read the quoted sudo man page in the answer. Especially the second paragraph for the `-k` option.

Comment: @user1346466 `sudo -k su;` — will remove current credentials AND it will NOT store new credentials. Therefore, make it two distinct commands: `sudo -k; sudo su;` — will remove current credentials till the next `sudo su` which is called at once but DOES store new credentials.

Answer (score 5):

Shawn's answer is great but there is an additional configuration option that might be useful in this situation.

From `man sudoers`:

> **tty_tickets**
>
> If set, users must authenticate on a per-tty basis.  With this flag enabled, sudo will use a file named for the tty the user is logged in on in the user's time stamp directory.  If disabled, the time stamp of the directory is used instead.
>
> This flag is on by default.

From `man sudo`:

> When the tty_tickets option is enabled in sudoers, the time stamp has per-tty granularity but still may outlive the user's session.  On Linux systems where the devpts filesystem is used, Solaris systems with the devices filesystem, as well as other systems that utilize a devfs filesystem that monotonically increase the inode number of devices as they are created (such as Mac OS X), sudo is able to determine when a tty-based time stamp file is stale and will ignore it.  **Administrators should not rely on this feature as it is not universally available.**

I think its relatively new. If your system supports it, if you logout then login, sudo will request your password again. (I have `sudo -K` in my shells logout script too.)