# What does "sudo -v" stands for in the sudoers-man-page

Tags: sudo

The basis for this question is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8529/26152) answer. In the sudoers man-page it is stated that:

> **timestamp_timeout**
>
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a passwd again.
>
> ...
>
> This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via “sudo -v” and “sudo -k” respectively.

What is actually referred to here in the last sentence regarding the **create**?

> This can be used to allow users to create ... their own time stamps via “sudo -v” ....

The `sudo -v` command already exists and is not dependent on `timestamp_timeout` as far as I can see. So where and how is that information in the man-page helping? What would be a practical usecase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the `sudo` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html):

```
-v, --validate
     Update the user's cached credentials, authenticating the user
     if necessary.  For the sudoers plugin, this extends the sudo
     timeout for another 15 minutes by default, but does not run a
     command.  Not all security policies support cached
     credentials.
```

Assuming a timeout is allowed for sudo (`timestamp_timeout` is greater zero), a long running script that repeatedly uses `sudo` can run `sudo -v` in a loop in the background, so that the user only has to authenticate to `sudo` *once*, at the start of the script. The background `sudo -v` loop will then keep extending the timeout (each time creating a *newer* timestamp). I have seen software installation scripts that need to invoke `sudo` a few times, each step potentially taking a long time to complete due to downloading, use `sudo -v` in this fashion.