# disable my own sudo for current shell?

Tags: sudo, authentication

Is it possible to prevent `sudo` from gaining root without password *only in the current session* (e.g. bash shell process?)

I've noticed that ruby's `bundle` underhandedly used my `sudo` powers, without asking, to write to system directories. Anyways, perhaps I didn't read enough about this wonderful tool, but is there a way to withdraw sudo blessings temporarily without reconfiguring `/etc/sudoers*`?

*Edit*: I currently have `NOPASSWD` enabled for the `sudo` group, which I'm a member of. I'd rather make the current process unable to `sudo` (e.g. by using something like `newgrp`) than give up NOPASSWD.

Comment: Possibly related: [Forcing sudo to prompt for a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/forcing-sudo-to-prompt-for-a-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing sudo to prompt for a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/forcing-sudo-to-prompt-for-a-password)

Comment: It's a way to do it (remove NOPASSWD, set a long timeout, manually expire as needed). I'd prefer to do something like newgrp to change the current PID's notion of who I am (and remove myself from the `sudo` group which I configured to sudo without password)

Comment: Details added to question

Answer (score 1):

$ alias sudo="echo sudon't "

$ sudo su - root

sudon't su - root

This will just break it where it's calling sudo, unless it's calling the full path like /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: This won't work for the case described in the question, where sudo is called within an application itself.

Comment: Aha! But it's a good idea. `ln -s /bin/true /tmp/sudo; PATH=/tmp:"$PATH"` finally breaks `bundle`. Seems like they just call sudo from the PATH, without hardcoding its location (which makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea would be easily doable by means of a small "set-userID-root" program which would only perform a `setgroups(2)` with all the current groups (as per `getgroups(2)`) except the `sudo` one, effectively dropping it. The set-userID-root is required because `setgroups(2)` is a privileged operation.

On Linux it could even be simpler as you could leverage the `capabilities(7)` hence make the executable program `setcap(8)`-ed to be `CAP_SETGID` rather than set-userID-root. At that point such dedicated program would only need to `capset(2)` itself to that capability before performing `setgroups(2)`.

**On the other hand**, though, [beware of dropping/changing group memberships inadvertently](https://lwn.net/Articles/621612/), because being member of a group is also used to *reduce* access rights e.g. to files & directories via ACLs purposefully placed.

That said, by leveraging the (Linux specific) `setpriv(1)` command (if available on your system) you can harness a proof-of-concept made as a shell function, like the below in which I'm using `sudo` itself (given that you are `NOPASSWD`) as the "set-userID-root enabler":

```bsh
# NOTE: this one uses Bash facilities
dropgrp() {
    local groups grp="${1:?Specify group to drop}" IFS=; shift
    IFS=: read -ra grent < <(getent group "$grp")
    groups=(${GROUPS[@]/${grent[2]}})
    IFS=,; sudo setpriv --reuid "$EUID" --regid "$GROUPS" --groups "${groups[*]}" "$@"
}
```

You would then run `$ dropgrp sudo bundle` (the `sudo` in there refers to the group name, not the command), and when that `bundle` program invokes `sudo` (the command) it will ask for your password to proceed.